# Correlation functions of higher order

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-physics, correlation

First I'm going to give some context on the question. The question arose in reading one Physics paper, but the question is itself just about Math involved.

In "[The Quantum Theory of Optical Coherence](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.130.2529)" by Glauber, he defines what he calls $n$-th order correlation functions. In that context he has a set of $2n$ random variables $E^-(x_1),\dots ,E^-(x_n)$ and $E^+(x_{n+1}),\dots, E^+(x_{2n})$ and defines (here $\langle\rangle$ is a mean value) $$G^{(n)}(x_1,\dots x_n,x_{n+1},\dots, x_{2n})=\langle E^-(x_1)\cdots E^-(x_n)E^+(x_{n+1})\cdots E^+(x_{2n})\rangle\tag{1}$$

He calls this $G^{(n)}$ the $n$-th order correlation function.

Now, in the $n=1$ case we see that $G^{(1)}(x_1,x_2)$ is connected to the covariance of the two random variables: $$\operatorname{Cov}(E^-(x_1),E^+(x_2))=\langle E^-(x_1)E^+(x_2)\rangle -\langle E^-(x_1)\rangle \langle E^+(x_2)\rangle\tag{2}.$$

Therefore if we assume the means are set to zero, $G^{(1)}(x_1,x_2)$ is *exactly* the covariance of the two random variables $E^-(x_1)$ and $E^+(x_2)$.

Since the Pearson correlation coefficient is just the covariance normalized by dividing by the standard deviations, in this sense $G^{(1)}(x_1,x_2)$ codifies *linear* correlations between $E^-(x_1)$ and $E^+(x_2)$. So it is justified to call $G^{(1)}$ the first order correlation.

Now  $G^{(n)}$ involves $2n$ random variables.

1. Is there some sense in which an object like $G^{(n)}$, a mean value of $2n$ random variables, encodes $n$-th order correlations?
2. Is this some extension of the Pearson correlation coefficients to quantify correlations more general than linear correlations?
3. Finally, correlations for me is a relation between *two random variables*. What it even means to talk about a correlation between $2n$ random variables?